# Animate SVGs gradually

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I solve this. I need to animate on hover a div that contains two svgs or imgs, nevermind.
How can i trigger that when I hover inside of that div, the two imgs will e.g. move. Maybe with Javascript, but I can seem to target the img when on hover. There is only mouseover? which leaves the state changed forever. I need help. Thank you!

```html
<div class="circle">
<img id="line-1" src="line.svg" alt="line">
<img id="line-2" src="line.svg" alt="line">
<div>
```

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  border: 6px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}

#line-1 {
positin: absolute;
left: 0;
animation: slide 1s ease-in infinite;}

#line-2 {
positin: absolute;
right: 0;
animation: slide-otherway 1s ease-in infinite;}

@keyframes slide {
   0% {
left: 0;
}

100% {
left: 20px;
}
}

@keyframes slide-otherway {
   0% {
right: 0;
}

100% {
right: 20px;
}
}
```

Comment: Use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions), not CSS animations. And prefer transitioning the [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) property over the `left` or `right` properties.

Answer (score 0):

with mouseenter u also need to use mouseleave, mouseleave will trigger when ofc, the muse leaves